# Yii: How to create yii application object in another php application?

Tags: php, yii

I want to use Yii functions in another open source project (moodle, joomla, ...) So I can benefit Yii powerful models.
I put following code in one of the files (***ROOT/course/edit.php***):

```
$yii = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../mws/framework/yii.php';
$config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../mws/protected/config/main.php';
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', TRUE);
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);
require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config);
```

But I get following error:

> PHP warning 
>  
> include(edit.php.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory 
>   
> D:\WAMP\www\millms\mws\framework\YiiBase.php(427) 
>  
> 415
>   { 
> 416                             include($classFile); 
> 417
>   if(YII_DEBUG && basename(realpath($classFile))!==$className.'.php')
>   
> 418                                 throw new
>   CException(Yii::t('yii','Class name "{class}" does not match class
>   file "{file}".', array( 
> 419
>   '{class}'=>$className, 
> 420
>   '{file}'=>$classFile, 
> 421                                 )));
>   
> 422                             break; 
> 423
>   } 
> 424                     } 
> 425                 } 
> 426
>   else 
> 427                     include($className.'.php'); 
> 428
>   } 
> 429             else  // class name with namespace in PHP 5.3
>   
> 430             { 
> 431
>   $namespace=str_replace('\','.',ltrim($className,'\')); 
> 432
>   if(($path=self::getPathOfAlias($namespace))!==false) 
> 433
>   include($path.'.php'); 
> 434                 else 
> 435
>   return false; 
> 436             } 
> 437             return
>   class_exists($className,false) || interface_exists($className,false);
>   
> 438         } 
> 439         return true; 
>  
> Stack Trace
>   
> #0     
> + 
>  D:\WAMP\www\millms\mws\framework\YiiBase.php(427):
>   YiiBase::autoload() 
> #1     
>  unknown(0):
>   YiiBase::autoload("edit.php") 
> #2   
>  unknown(0):
>   spl_autoload_call("edit.php") 
> #3   
> – 
>   D:\WAMP\www\millms\lib\formslib.php(831): is_a("edit.php",
>   "moodle_url") 
>  
> 826         static $formcounter = 1; 
> 827 
>   
> 828         HTML_Common::HTML_Common($attributes); 
> 829
>   $target = empty($target) ? array() : array('target' => $target);
>   
> 830         $this->_formName = $formName; 
> 831         if
>   (is_a($action, 'moodle_url')){ 
> 832             $this->_pageparams
>   = $action->hidden_params_out(); 
> 833             $action = $action->out(true); 
> 834         } else { 
> 835
>   $this->_pageparams = ''; 
> 836         } 
>  
> #4     
> – 
>   D:\WAMP\www\millms\lib\formslib.php(115):
>   MoodleQuickForm->MoodleQuickForm("course_edit_form", "post",
>   "edit.php", "", ...) 
>  
> 110             $action =
>   strip_querystring(qualified_me()); 
> 111         } 
> 112  
> 113 
>   $this->_formname = get_class($this); // '_form' suffix kept in order
>   to prevent collisions of form id and other element 
> 114
>   $this->_customdata = $customdata; 
> 115         $this->_form =& new
>   MoodleQuickForm($this->_formname, $method, $action, $target,
>   $attributes); 
> 116         if (!$editable){ 
> 117
>   $this->_form->hardFreeze(); 
> 118         } 
> 119
>   $this->set_upload_manager(new upload_manager()); 
> 120  
>  
> #5
>      
> – 
>  D:\WAMP\www\millms\course\edit.php(448):
>   moodleform->moodleform("edit.php", array("course" => null, "category"
>   => stdClass)) 
>  
> 443     } 
> 444 } 
> 445  
> 446  
> 447 /// first create the form 
> 448 $editform = new
>   course_edit_form('edit.php', compact('course', 'category')); 
> 449
>   // now override defaults if course already exists 
> 450 if
>   (!empty($course)) { 
> 451     $course->enrolpassword =
>   $course->password; // we need some other name for password field
>   MDL-9929 
> 452     $editform->set_data($course); 
> 453 }

**How I can Create A raw Yii Application Object?**

Comment: Do you want to use just CModel? Or are you also interested in CActiveRecord?

Comment: I want to use all classes, specially db related ones.